# Is $\forall x(P(x)\to Q(x)) \to (\forall x(P(x)) \to \forall x(Q(x)))$ valid?

Tags: logic

$\forall x(P(x)\to Q(x)) \to (\forall x(P(x)) \to \forall x(Q(x)))$

I have a strong feeling that it is, because either all $p(x)$ are true but then also all $q(x)$ are true. Else one $p(x)$ is false and it is directly valid.

Is my argumentation correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a strong feeling that it is, because either all $p(x)$ are true but then also all $q(x)$ are true. Else one $p(x)$ is false and it is directly valid.
>
> Is my argumentation correct ?

Yes, "Assuming $P(x)\to Q(x)$ holds for any $x$, infers that either $Q(x)$ holds for every $x$ *or* $P(x)$ does not hold for some $x$."

Thus, the conditional, $((\forall x~(P(x) \to ~Q(x)) )\to((\forall x~P(x))\to (\forall x~Q(x)))$, is valid.

- "If $Q(x)$ holds whenever $P(x)$ does, then $Q(x)$ will hold everywhere if $P(x)$ holds everywhere."

---

$$\begin{array}{r:l|rlr}1 & \quad\forall x ~(P(x)\to Q(x)) & &\text{assume} & \text{assumption I}\\ 2 & \qquad \forall x~P(x) & & \text{assume} &  \text{assumption II}\\ 3& \qquad\quad P(c) & 2 & \forall - & \text{arbitrary }c \\ 4 & \qquad\quad P(c)\to Q(c) & 1& \forall - \\ 5 &\qquad\quad Qc & 3,4 & \to- \\ 6 & \qquad \forall x~ Q(x) & 5 & \forall + & \text{discharge }c\\ 7 & \quad \forall x~P(x)~\to~\forall x~Q(x) & 2,6 & \to + & \text{discharge II} \\ 8 & (\forall x~(P(x)\to Q(x)))~\to~((\forall x~P(x))\to(\forall x~Q(x))) & 1,7 & \to+ &\text{discharge I}\end{array}$$

Answer (score 2):

It is correct

Sorry, I'll add more details about this:

First: if we have that for every P(x), then Q(x)
Then, if all P(x) are true, then obviously all Q(x) are true too

If we try to demonstrate this implication, we'd have to negate the conclusion, to see if we get a contradiction:

!(∀x(P(x))→∀x(Q(x))) = !(!∀x(P(x)) or ∀x(Q(x))) = (∀x(P(x)) and !∀x(Q(x))) = (∀x(P(x)) and Ex(!Q(x)))

Then, we have that every P(x) is true, and that, for some of them, Q(x) is false

But it contradicts our premise that ∀x(P(x)→Q(x)), because exists at least 1 x where this doesn't happens

As we found a contradiction by negating the conclusion, then the premise must be true

Also, I'd suggest to add parentheses for more clarity (you have some extra ones):

∀x(P(x)→Q(x))→(∀x(P(x))→∀x(Q(x)))

Answer (score 1):

If for all $x$, $P(x)$ is true, then by the given assumption, $Q(x)$ is true for each and thus all $x$.

The converse isn't necessarily true.